# My remote repos throw no errors, but also have no content

Tags: artifactory

Basically what it says on the tin. I have two instances of Artifactory running and I want to set up a local repo on Artifactory instance A to be a remote repo on Artifactory instance B. I type in the correct path (and every plausible variation of it) and when I click "Test" it says everything is good to go. I set up the correct password authentication, too, and clicking "Test" also says everything is good. I made sure that no repo was blacked out or anything and I checked the system logs to ensure that nothing went wrong silently.

And yet, I can't actually query any data from that repo. Artifactory says the remote repo contains zero Artifacts. If I try to download a specific file from that repo, I get a 404.

I tried messing about randomly with the settings, which I suppose unsurprisingly didn't work. But I get no error message, no warnings, no odd behaviors. I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my mistake turned out to be that the repository key it asks for isn't the repository key of the remote repo, but the repository key of the local repo you want to create. I suppose this is there to let you have a remote repo with a different public-facing name than the actual repo it pulls from. Otherwise you have to type in myartifactory.com/my-repo-local and then my-repo-local again in the repository key.

Comment: Hi, so, if you are already on the naming repositories state of mind, I would recommend this white-paper on Repository Naming Conventions:
https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/
. Hope it will assist :)

Comment: Also, it is considered best practice to place repositories under a virtual one (regardless if it is a single local repo or several repositories. In your case, you should have probably placed both the local and remote repositories under a single virtual one since according to your update they share similar context.
 Hope it will assist and not confuse.